# Is this a summatory multiplication?

Tags: probability, notation

I'm learning probability and I've just found this on a book:

[image]

The bold **$x$** is $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$.

I'm not sure what this means. I think I have to multiply all of the sums of each element of the bold **$x$**, like this:

$$\sum_xP(x)=\sum_{x_1}P(x_1)·\sum_{x_2}P(x_1,x_2)·...·\sum_{x_n}P(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$$

Is that correct?

By the way, I'm trying to calculate the joint probability.

You can find the book I'm using [here](http://www.ia.uned.es/~fjdiez/libros/intro-mgp.pdf), page 15.

Comment: yup, that's good

Comment: I'd guess that it just means what it says. No multiplication (where do you see a multiplication sign?), just add up the values $P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ over all values of the vector $\mathbf x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$.

Comment: That's notation is confusing (at least for someone that hasn't studied maths for a while). I have asked this other question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207929/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-joint-probability-of-two-variables, because I don't understand what $\sum_{x_2}P(x_1,x_2)$ means.

Comment: @bof Could you please add an answer with a small example? I don't understand what it says. If I know it, I wouldn't asked this question.

Comment: Suppose $n=3$ and each $x_i$ takes values $0$ and $1$. Then I would guess that $$\Sigma_{x_1}\Sigma_{x_2}\Sigma_{x_3}P(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\Sigma_{x_1=0}^1\Sigma_{x_2=0}^1\Sigma_{x_3=0}^1P(x_1,x_2,x_3)=P(0,0,0)+P(0,0,1)+P(0,1,0)+P(0,1,1)+P(1,0,0,)+P(1,0,1)+P(1,1,0)+P(1,1,1).$$ Maybe the context (which you have not shared with us) suggests some other meaning. But with nothing else to go on, I would go with the simplest and most obvious interpretation.

Comment: @bof Thanks for your comment. The context is on the book I have referenced at the end of the question. And my question is only about a definition that I don't understand. Maybe my problem is with notation, not with probability. Thanks again.