# How to calculate a lot of summation in the same expression

Tags: probability, summation, notation

I'm learning probability and I've just found this on a book:

$$\sum_xP(x)=\sum_{x_1}···\sum_{x_n}P(x_1,...,x_n)=1$$

The bold **$x$** is $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$.

**My question is**: How can I compute those $\sum_{x_1}...\sum_{x_n}$?

I think the expression means this (multiply each summation):

$$\sum_xP(x)=\sum_{x_1}P(x_1)·\sum_{x_2}P(x_1,x_2)·...·\sum_{x_n}P(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$$

By the way, I'm trying to calculate the joint probability.

Comment: You fix $x_1$ and sum over all possible values of $x_2$. The result is not  a number but a function of $x_1$.

Comment: Please, do not downvote. I can read. Your comment is enough to make me remove the image. Thanks.